# Small program to get detailed information on images

Tags: software-rec, images, adobe-photoshop, image-viewer

I'm looking for a small program that will show be a LOT of detailed information about media files, specifically images. For example, I'd like to know if a .BMP file is Windows or OS/2, Compressed, etc.

Windows tells me the basics and Photoshop can read files just fine, but I want to know *exactly* what format an image is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ImageMagick's](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) `identify`:

```
$ identify -verbose $file
Image: We Live No More by vhm_alex.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1920x1200+0+0
  Resolution: 100x100
  Print size: 19.2x12
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: RGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 119.898 (0.470189)
      standard deviation: 119.244 (0.467623)
      kurtosis: -1.90522
      skewness: 0.149589
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 121.541 (0.476631)
      standard deviation: 118.848 (0.46607)
      kurtosis: -1.9068
      skewness: 0.135223
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 123.619 (0.484782)
      standard deviation: 118.213 (0.463581)
      kurtosis: -1.90561
      skewness: 0.117145
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 121.686 (0.477201)
      standard deviation: 118.769 (0.465761)
      kurtosis: -1.90559
      skewness: 0.133856
  Rendering intent: Undefined
  Interlace: JPEG
  Background color: white
  Border color: rgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 1920x1200+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 93
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2011-07-06T20:16:05+03:00
    date:modify: 2010-05-11T16:11:32+03:00
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x1,1x1,1x1
    signature: b35ad216a554f94d6ce0319b08bf18e1047b09fe835bace9e92fa5940f1bc3fe
  Profiles:
    Profile-APP12: 15 bytes
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 759KBB
  Number pixels: 2.304MB
  Pixels per second: 25.6MB
  User time: 0.080u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.089
  Version: ImageMagick 6.7.1-0 2011-07-10 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```